# How to access value from YAML key/value pair list item?

Tags: ansible, yaml, jinja2

If I have the following YAML list item (I think that's what it's called) which is expressed as a key/value pair, how do I read the value?  I've been looking through the YAML documentation and didn't see this situation discussed.

```
---
apache_vhosts:
  - servername: localhost
    documentroot: "/var/www/html"
```

I want to do something like this and set install_path to "/var/www/html":

```
...
# This doesn't work
install_path: "{{ apache_vhosts.servername[documentroot] }}"
```

Comment: You don't *read a value* in YAML, because YAML is not a programming language. It seems you are using a templating language but do not tell us which one or in what context.

Comment: I added the ansible and jinja2 tags. Please add as much context as necessary next time for others to understand what you are working with. YAML is a language of its own, not only used in ansible.

Comment: I'm sorry.  This is a section from an Ansible playbook and I'm trying to assign one YAML variable with the value of another variable higher up in the file.

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Comment: @tinita, no your answer didn't work.  But thanks just the same.

Comment: tinita answer is the solution. What do you mean when you say that it doesn't work? As `apache_vhosts` is a list, do you iterate over it through a `list_items` loop? Can you add Ansible code of your use of all this variables (so we can know what you're trying to achieve)?

Answer (score 0):

`apache_vhosts` is a list of mappings. You are trying to access the key `servername` from this list, but lists don't have keys.
Also I don't know what you want to achieve with `.servername[documentroot]`.

My guess is you need:
`apache_vhosts[0].documentroot` (the first element of apache_vhosts -> key documentroot)

Please have a look at the [Jinja2 Template Docs](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/).
Edit: Probably better for your case: [Ansible Templating](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_templating.html)